# How to fund an address in foundry test

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

How can I fund an EOA inside a test case with Foundry.

Assume I have an NFT contract, want to test the minting functionality and I want to have an EOA that owns enough ether to mint, since users have to send ether to mint it.

Let's say I have

```
contract NFTCollectionTest is Test {
   ...
   function testMint() public {
      address someRandomUser = vm.addr(1);
      vm.prank(someRandomUser);
      nftCollection.mint{value: 0.01 ether}();
      ...
   }
}
```

But the test case failed. When I run the foundry test with more verbosity `-vvvv` I can see that `"EvmError: OutOfFund"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most such cases you need to find a vm function that does what you want. I recommend you check out this [link](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/environment). In this case it's vm.deal where you pass in the address as well as the amount of ether you want to give this address.

```
contract NFTCollectionTest is Test {
   ...
   function testMint() public {
      address someRandomUser = vm.addr(1);
      vm.prank(someRandomUser);
      vm.deal(someRandomUser, 1 ether);
      nftCollection.mint{value: 0.01 ether}();
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to `deal` eth to a user when we prank, but if we send eth without pranking, the value is sent? Does the Test contract have unlimited funds?

Answer (score 0):

While you can `deal` and separately `prank`, you can use `hoax` to do this in one step:

```
hoax(user);
myContract.doSomething();
```

`hoax` optionally accepts a second parameter that is the ETH balance to deal to the address. If not used, will default to 2^128 wei

Per docs: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/hoax